# Install extension via composer - permission denied

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I try Install via composer free extension Magento 2 SMTP.

- installation guide:
  https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/download/

I run  first command:

```
php composer.phar require mageplaza/module-smtp
```

Then I get error(permission denied):
[image]

Anyone know how to solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212362/composer-file-put-contents-composer-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission

Comment: The same error: b2b is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

Comment: do you have access to the root account?

Comment: yes i have access to root

Comment: harri, I run command from root but now get: chown -R b2b .composer/
chown: cannot access '.composer/': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Set 777 to vendor folder recursively. Run:
sudo chmod -R 777 ./vendor/

Comment: I run this command but get error: 
b2b@b2b:~/domains/bstyle.pl/public_html$  sudo chmod -R 777 ./vendor/
[sudo] password for b2b:
[GET ERROR]: b2b is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.